# Is Search Service application inside list Apps?

Tags: 2013, search, app

If Search service application work and get result form inside Apps I mean if I have list inside app SharePoint-hosted and have list from visual studio added inside app can the search service get data from this service and how to get that?

More Description or in other words :
I made a SharePoint-hosted app project and add to this project a list from Visual studio and use this list in my app as insert update delete items my question is :
If I enable search service application in my site collection as search service can it search inside the list which I created inside app or not ? and how ?

Comment: Can you please try to clarify your question, it does not really make sense now.

Comment: I edit more description